# Parsing HTML Table with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, mysql, parsing

I'm scraping the following html table:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="Name">A</td>
  <td class="S1">5</td>
  <td class="S2">6</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

My goal is to use Html_simple_dom in order to parse the data and input the values into a MySQL database. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');
include('dbconnect.php');
$html = file_get_html('url');
$table = $html->find('table');
foreach ($table->find('tr') as $row) {
 foreach ($row->find('td[class=Name]') as $cell) {
  $name = $cell->plaintext;
  }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that my $name variable is actually an array. I'm getting stuck with duplicates if I do this instead:

```
foreach ($table->find('tr') as $row) {
 foreach ($row->find('td[class=Name]') as $cell) {
  }
  $name = $cell->plaintext;
}
```

My ultimate goal would be a MySQL query such as this:

```
$sql = Insert into ScoreTable (Score1, Score2)
       Values ($S1, $S2)
       Where PName = $Name
```

However I can't separate the array values I'm getting when I "find" and I can't even isolate the html elements into variables. Where am I going wrong?

edit: Fixed what my goal is.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample of the html table.  Absent that, what I see is that you're only going to get the last row because `$name` is *not* an array, and it is being reassigned every time through the nested foreach loops.

Comment: I've included a simplified html table above which approximates what I'm trying to scrape.

Comment: I would expect you could build your own data structure like this:  ```foreach $table->find('tr') as $row) { $data = array('name' => $row>find('td[class=Name]')->plaintext, 'S1' =>  $row>find('td[class=S1]')->plaintext, 'S2 => $row>find('td[class=Name]')->plaintext); }``` assuming that your syntax for finding the classname is correct.  I haven't used html_simple_dom, but I would expect it works this way.

Comment: Would an array of the data be more difficult to insert into a MySQL database?

Comment: You could either iterate through the array and make an insert each time, or you could build the insert statement before executing it.

Comment: oops, I caught a mistake... it should be ```$data[] = array( ...```

Comment: and, I copied and pasted without changing `class=Name` to `class=S2`.  Too close to bedtime...

Comment: I caught the class=S2. I updated the $data, however I'm getting an error of 
    Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: That means the `find()` method didn't find what it was looking for, so when we asked for the `plaintext` property, there was no object (what it should have found) for it to get the property from.  This would happen if you have `tr`s without the classes you're looking for.  My bad, I shouldn't have chained it together.  You'll have to test to see if the `find()` method actually is successful before trying to get the `plaintext`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use cicly if need only one value. You can get first element of returned array or use second params of find()

See here http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

> // Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)
>
> $ret = $html->find('a', 0);

You MYSQL insert has wrong format see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html  Correct is

> INSERT INTO ScoreTable (Score1, Score2, Pname) VALUES ('$S1', '$S2','$name')

And I don't know that's in you "dbconnect.php". But if there is something like **"$mysqli = mysqli_connect"** your code is

```
foreach ($table->find('tr') as $row) {
   $name =$row->find('td.Name',0)->plaintext;
   $S1 =$row->find('td.S1',0)->plaintext;
   $S2 =$row->find('td.S2',0)->plaintext;
   if (!is_null($name)) { // if found name
          $name=$mysqli->real_escape_string($name); // Escapes special characters
          $S1=$mysqli->real_escape_string($S1);
          $S2=$mysqli->real_escape_string($S2);

         if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ScoreTable (Score1, Score2, Pname) VALUES ('$S1', '$S2','$name')") === TRUE) {//Make SQL query and check is it success
                echo "Sccess\n";
         }
   }

}
```

Check your dbconnect.php and past needed link-to-connection variable instead $mysqli

**Also it's strognly recommend to use real_escape_string() to escapes special characters.** Especially if you work with outside data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best answer, but it's working:

HTML Table scraped from a website:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="Name">A</td>
  <td class="S1">5</td>
  <td class="S2">6</td>
 </td>
</table>
```

I ended up creating an array for each class I was scraping, combining it all into a single array, then updating the database from the merged array:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('url', TRUE);

$table = $html->find('table',0);
foreach($table->find('tr') as $row){

$g_name = array()
foreach($row->find('td[class=Name]') as $cell{
 $g_name['Name'] = $cell->plaintext;
}

$g_s1 = array()
foreach($row->find('td[class=S1]') as $cell{
 $g_s1['S1'] = $cell->plaintext;
}

$g_s2 = array()
foreach($row->find('td[class=S2]') as $cell{
 $g_s2['S2'] = $cell->plaintext;
}

$data = array_merge($g_name,$g_s1,$g_s2);
$sql = "Update table SET
Rd1='".$data['S1']."',
Rd2='".$data['S2']."',
WHERE Player = '".$data['Name']."';

}
?>
```

I then close my MySQL connection or display errors etc...
I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it's working.

Thanks all for your help.